# Get AWS Principal Tag Value of a Federated User

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

We are using AWS SSO with an External Identity Provider and have enabled ABAC (Attributes for Access Control). We are passing some session tags like `SSMSessionRunAs`. Can we get the value of the session/principal tag being passed via AWS CLI assuming that the user currently configured in the shell is the Federated user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you're passing session tags via AWS SSO (IAM Identity Center), the general question is whether it is possible to get the value of an AWS session tag.

There seems to be no way to get the *full* set of AWS session tags, neither via an API call nor in the console. Rather, it is only possible to get partial visibility into the current AWS session tags in two ways:

1. Examine CloudTrail logs. This only shows you new tags being *explicitly* applied to newly created sessions, as well as incoming transitive session tags.
2. Write IAM policies to allow/deny access using a `Condition` clause with `${principalTag/TAG_NAME}`.

#### 1. CloudTrail Logs

CloudTrail logs show a subset of session tags when the following API calls are made: `AssumeRole`, `AssumeRoleWithSAML`, `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`, and `GetFederationToken` (ref: [Passing session tags in AWS STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_session-tags.html))

In the corresponding CloudTrail events, you see:

- Tags *explicitly* passed in the API call which apply to the new session; and
- Incoming transitive session tags, which propagate to the new session. (Does not apply to `AssumeRoleWithSAML` and `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`, which are called without an existing session.)

However, these CloudTrail events do *not* include current, non-transitive session tags, which are not inherited by the new session. (If there is a way to see them, I would like to know...)

##### Example

Here is an excerpt showing `requestParameters` from a CloudTrail event for an `AssumeRole` call:

```json
"requestParameters": {
    "incomingTransitiveTags": {
        "TagKey1": "TagValue1"
    },
    "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/TestTagRole1",
    "roleSessionName": "some-role-session-name",
    "tags": [
        {
            "key": "TagKey4",
            "value": "TagValue4"
        },
        {
            "key": "TagKey5",
            "value": "TagValue5"
        }
    ]
    "transitiveTagKeys": [
        "TagKey4"
    ]
}
```

It reveals the following:

- The call is made from a session which has the `TagKey1: TagValue1` transitive session tag.
- The call explicitly applies tags to the *new* session: `TagKey4: TagValue4`; `TagKey5: TagValue5`
- The new session tag `TagKey4: TagValue4` is transitive.

However, the event entry does *not* show the following:

- The call is made from a session which also has two non-transitive session tags: `TagKey2: TagValue2`; `TagKey3: TagValue3`
- `TagKey2` was *explicitly* passed via a previous `AssumeRole*` call, and thus appears in an earlier CloudTrail event.
- `TagKey3` was *implicitly* applied via an IAM user/role tag and as such does not appear on any visible session record (to my knowledge).

##### Aside: Programmatic access to CloudTrail

While [CloudTrail can also be accessed via an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), there is a delay of several minutes for an event to appear in its event history, which seems to make it infeasible to test for session tags programmatically in real-time.

#### 2. IAM policies

You could make use of IAM policies which allow or deny based on `${principalTag/TAG_NAME}`. For instance, the below policy will allow the listing of S3 objects if the S3 prefix matches the value of session tag `SessionTag`:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::session-tags-test",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": "${aws:PrincipalTag/SessionTag}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, it is possible to test for an exact value of a current session tag `SessionTag` by attempting to list objects:

```
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket session-tags-test --prefix SessionTagValue

$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket session-tags-test --prefix IncorrectValue
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

Alternatively, to test for the presence of `SessionTag`, regardless of its value, the `Condition` element in the above policy can be adjusted to use the `Null` condition operator:

```json
"Condition": {
    "Null": {
        "aws:PrincipalTag/SessionTag": "false"
    }
}
```